# Query syntax error when bulk-deleting in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I try to executer bulk delete using Hibernate HQL query, following [reference manunal](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct) but I get a query syntax error. This line

```
final Query qry = getSession(false).createQuery(" delete from NewCalendarDay");
```

causes exception:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: query must begin with SELECT or FROM: delete [ delete from pl.com.bms.avaro.staticData.model.NewCalendarDay ]

Class in which the code is executed extends `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport`, so `getSession()` method should return `org.hibernate.Session`.
I use spring v. 2.5.5 and Hibernate v. 3.2.6.ga

Should I configure something to be able to bulk-delete or what?

**EDIT**
Bozho asked for complete stack trace, so here it goes:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query must begin with SELECT or FROM: delete [ delete from pl.com.bms.avaro.staticData.model.NewCalendarDay ]
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClauseParser.token(ClauseParser.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.PreprocessingParser.token(PreprocessingParser.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ParserHelper.parse(ParserHelper.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
    at pl.com.bms.avaro.staticData.dao.implementations.NewCalendarDayDaoImpl.deleteCalendarDaysForYear(NewCalendarDayDaoImpl.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy43.deleteCalendarDaysForYear(Unknown Source)
    at pl.com.bms.avaro.staticData.dao.tests.TestCalendarDayDaoImpl.testFindByDateCal(TestCalendarDayDaoImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.ConditionalTestCase.runBare(ConditionalTestCase.java:76)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: You can view this for better anderstanding 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909709/hibernate-classicquerytranslatorfactory-vs-astquerytranslatorfactory][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909709/hibernate-classicquerytranslatorfactory-vs-astquerytranslatorfactory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get rid of the leading whitespace for a start. Then execute the query using `query.executeUpdate()`

Then, even if this works for you, I wouldn't advice using HQL to delete entities. In case they have any relations, these will not be cascaded and you will end up with inconsistencies.

Select all objects and call `session.remove(entity)` on each. Of course, if you don't have any x-to-x relationships, you can proceed with the HQL, but be careful if you add such in the future.

**Update:** you might be having something like this in your hibernate configurations:

```
<prop
 key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
</prop>
```

It makes Hibernate use the classic parser. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Removing trailing whitespace didn't help. Interface org.hibernate.Session doesn't define executeUpdate method so I can't use it. I know premature optimization is a root of all evil but still I think loading objects only to have them deleted is a waste of resources. And I don't understand how a code almost copied from reference manual can fail this way.

Comment: @Tadeusz Kopec sorry, I meant to use the `executeUpdate` method of the `Query` object. Please give the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Added stacktrace to the question. To execute query I have to create it first, but creation fails :-)

Comment: I found this configuration entry and removed it - it works. Great. Now I have to find out who put this configuration and why. Anyway, at least tests work so I hope it didn't spoil any other thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Did you find out why that is added in the code previously. Removing that impacted anywhere ? I am facing the same problem now

Comment: @hop Sorry, it was two years ago and I changed work since then. Now I don't remember why it was added. But I managed to remove it, so it wasn't so hard.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error and to comment this property
org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property-->

solves the problem.