# How to fix missing org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory in hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-6.x

I am migrating spring framework from 5.* to 6. I am getting error:

> hql is missing in
> ‘org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory’.

How to fix this?

I tried searching for the class in other packages of hibernate but fail to get it.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909709/hibernate-classicquerytranslatorfactory-vs-astquerytranslatorfactory