# Why does my HQL query return "must begin with select or from"?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to execute an HQL delete query, but it is giving an exception: "Query must begin with select or from".

```
 transaction = session.beginTransaction();
Query query=session.createQuery("DELETE FROM category where categoryid = :categoryid");
            query.setParameter("categoryid", id);
            int result=query.executeUpdate();
        transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [Query syntax error when bulk-deleting in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312124/query-syntax-error-when-bulk-deleting-in-hibernate)

Since you SQL looks correct, it seems that it may be the query parser you are using perhaps - so ensure that you aren't using:

```
<prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
```

Comment: once I remove this property  <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop> I am getting following error  "ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken"   in the following query "from Adminuser where userid = :userid and password = :password"

Comment: Have you checked Google? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ClassNotFoundException%3A+org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken&oq=ClassNotFoundException%3A+org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken